# Yocto on AM65x-evm, old SoC revision

Tags: yocto, texas-instruments

I'm tring to get yocto build up and running on TMDX654IDKEVM board. Unfortunally I have old board revision populated with first version of SoC. And problem is I didn't find out way how to tell yocto to build image for this old SoC.

Here is what I tried:

```
$ git clone git://git.yoctoproject.org/poky
$ git clone git://git.yoctoproject.org/meta-arm
$ git clone git://git.yoctoproject.org/meta-ti
$ git checkout dunfell #for all above
$ . poky/oe-init-build-env
$ bitbake-layers add-layer ../meta-arm/meta-arm-toolchain/
$ bitbake-layers add-layer ../meta-arm/meta-arm/
$ bitbake-layers add-layer ../meta-ti/
$ vim conf/local.conf  # set MACHINE=am65xx-evm
$ bitbake core-image-minimal
$ wic create sdimage-bootdisk -e core-image-minimal
$ dd if=./sdimage-bootpart-<date>-mmcblk0.direct of=<path>
```

This will successfully create my SD card in  but it won't boot at all. But if I tried to change sysfw.itb with one from build/deploy directory that have sr1 in its name. I can successfully run into uboot. When I start booting I can see kernel boot log and thet board reset and I'm back in uboot. It's look like watchdog. No error message, nothing.

Observation about sr1 in sysfw.itb file name lead me to conclusion that I have image for wrong SoC version. So i tried to look into meta-ti and found files k3r5.conf and k3r5-sr2.conf in conf/multiconfig folder. I believe these files should be solution for my problem but because I'm totally new to yocto I don't how to use them properly.

I discovered that they contain something like multiconfig. And tried to execute:

```
$ bitbake mc:k3r5:core-image-minimal
```

This command build something more that just core-image-minimal but when I tried to get SD card image using:

```
$ wic create sdimage-bootdisk -e mc:k3r5:core-image-minimal
```

Nothing is done.

Can you please share some informations about how to use multiconfig correctly? And how to correctly generate my SD card image? Many thanks in advance! :)

Comment: I will look like idiot but that strange behaviour with reset and returning back to uboot was given by my power source... having analogue power source I had current limit set almost at required power and missed that very short LED blink...

Well ...  now I'm able to boot correctly, but only if I manually change bootloader to one intended for SR1 SoC revision. So, question is still valid, how I will instruct yocto to build image for SR1 and how I will use multiconfig correctly to do that?

Comment: Since there are config files with the names k3r5 and k3r5-sr2, then you can change target machine under conf/local.conf to these new ones and try them. So for the [k3r5](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-ti/tree/conf/machine/am65xx-evm-k3r5.conf), you can change the MACHINE variable in conf/local.conf to am65xx-evm-k3r5.

Comment: @MohammedOsama I tried it today, succesfully get thru compilation, but wic create nothing. Complaining "No boot files defined, IMAGE_BOOT_FILES unset for entry #1". 

Beeing completly new to this, I simply don't know where to dig to get informations. :/

I just found out that when I use MACHINE=am65xx-evm and manually change sysfw.itb to be that one without "sr2" in tmp/deploy/am65xx-evm/ everything will work. But there have to be clean way to do this, haven't it?

Comment: I found some comments [here](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-ti/tree/conf/machine/include/am65xx.inc?h=dunfell#n25) in line 25. This file is included in the [am65xx-evm](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-ti/tree/conf/machine/am65xx-evm.conf?h=dunfell#n5) machine conf file. So, it seems as you are saying the default is SR2 version. To change this you can change the recipe (Name of the file used by Yocto to download, build and install certain software) of sysfw.

Comment: The recipe seems to be one of the files [here](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-ti/tree/recipes-bsp/ti-sci-fw?h=dunfell) ending with .bb extension. you just need to change the do_deploy function to make sysfw.itb symbolic link points to the one you need.